# urlrewrite htaccess on symbolic directory

Tags: linux, .htaccess, symbolic-link, rewrite

I have a problem using htaccess url rewrite on a symbolic folder. 
Below is the line which i am using in htaccess file for url rewriting.

```
RewriteRule ^global/css/([0-9]+)/([a-z-_]+)\.css$ global/less/index.php?site_id=$1&file=$2 [L]
```

"global" is my symbolic directory

This rule works fine when I use it on other then symbolic directory. But it does not work on symbolic directory.

it is working on my live server but not working on my local test server. what other configuration is required to make it work.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran across a similar problem, try looking in your httpd.conf file, check to see if you have an alias set to your global link, if so, try commenting it out and restart your server.

Answer (score 0):

debug mod_rewrite: use RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel directive(http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

....

RewriteLog "/var/log/rewrite.log" 
RewriteLogLevel 8

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^global/css/([0-9]+)/([a-z-_]+)\.css$ global/less/index.php?site_id=$1&file=$2 [L]
```